# Unable to download binascii

Tags: python-2.7

Hi i am a newbie in python. I have installed python 2.7.10 in windows(64 bit). I tried installing certain packages like binascii and zlib for my program but it is throwing the following error:
Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement binascii (from versions: )
No matching distributions found for binascii.
I used the command: pip install binascii
But I have successfully used pip command to install packages like requests suitcase etc.. 
How to rectify this error?

Answer (score 11):

Python 2.x and 3.x has binascii built-in. You should have `#import binascii` at the start of your code if you want to use it.